# integrating Xtext with SWT Styled text

Tags: swt, xtext, styledtext

I'm working on an eclipse plugin in which I have a wizard with several pages. on one of the pages, I need to integrate xtext editor in SWT styled text text area.

I have looked at documentation but didn't find any help in this regard.

Comment: did you research Xtext + Embedded Editor?

Comment: Yes i did search but these the problem is the results and examples are quite old and upon importing them i open another Pandora box. As the main issue is resolving their dependencies.

Comment: Have a look on http://techshashwat.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-add-xtext-dsl-editor-in-multi.html